# Only one attribute choice being saved at a time

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

I am creating choices for an Attribute however when I add 3 colour choices see example below and save only one of the colour choices is saved. Is this a known bug as this seems to be happening quite a lot now. If a known bug can any one offer a solution where all choices are saved instead of one at a time. Magento 1.7.0.2 bTW

Additional Information (FOR EXAMPLE)
Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes
Create a Color Attribute
Add Option > Green
Add Option > Blue
Add Option > Red
Save
View Attribute
Only the first attribute created is added. ie (Green)

Nothing to do with product!!!
Repeat

Create a Color Attribute
Add Option > Blue
Add Option > Red 
Save
View Attribute
Only the first attribute created is added. ie (Blue)

Comment: For me it is  not obvious what you are asking. Are you saying that you are trying to save custom options in a product in the backend but they are not being saved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's referring to adding attribute options to either a drop down or a multiselect. He's saying that if he adds multiple options and then saves the attribute, only one value is actually saved. Is that correct Richard? Could you also confirm the number of attribute options that are already created for this one attribute in particular?

Comment: Hi yes it is the initial creation of the choices for an attribute that will be used as part of an attribute set for a configurable product drop list. This attribute set has two options select colour and select size nothing special but all the choices seem to be ignored bar one at a time. ie if I add 6 colours choices only one one is added to the attribute.

Comment: Richard, can you tell us how many attribute options you have for that attribute though?

Comment: HI,I have 2 attributes one with 2 choices & one with 6 colour choices.

Comment: Are you using any 3th party extensions that might have any influence on the attributes, perhaps disable all extensions temporarily and also check for javascript errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got the the source of the problem as the checkout stages also were not proceeding to the next stage. The problem seems to have happened by the client updating the prototype libraries. I deleted the js/prototype/prototype.js and replaced it with the 1.7.0.2 package version and everything started working again... Problem now solved...